# Problem with next-js when link to another page

Tags: next.js

I have a problem with next js, when I link to another page works fine but when I come back to the home page, I'm not came back to the same location that I was before...

So expected, when I came back to be in the same location on the page that I was before, when I "link for more info..."

and by the way... I tried a lot things none works...

```
experimental: {
  scrollRestoration: true,
},
```

Comment: if you wanna to see I have a link https://test-kappa-neon-72.vercel.app/

Comment: I tried also, <script
   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
  __html: `history.scrollRestoration = "manual"`,
  }}
 />

Comment: I tried some stuff of this guys... https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/37893

Comment: I hope is someone out there, can help me, please...